# Customer First Name & Last Name Not Found In Shopify Get Orders API

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I am calling the below Shopify GET Orders API

```
/admin/api/2024-01/orders.json?status=any
```

JSON response for customer data is as below:

[image]

But I want to get the customer's `first name`, `last name`, `mobile`, `email`, and other customer data.

Please help to get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with Shopify, at the Admin API level, you have to set the privacy settings of your App, where you promise to not mess around with customer info should they grant you permission to see it. So for a custom App, not in App store, just fill it all out and ask for permission to see customer info. You get it. For a public App, they review your request, so you have to wait.

In your Partner account, for the App, under API keys, you'll find the links to privacy settings.

Comment: Actually, I have developed the store and an App in Shopify without creating a Partner account. Is it necessary to create a Partner account?

Comment: Yes. You cannot create an App without being a partner. Funny you say you developed an App without being a partner. You some kind of super hacker. Ha!